# Appstore: Can We Submit another version update when app is under developer release

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

My app is under developer release,

I want to submit another version upadate.

Do i need to release the app or Can I submit another update under developer release status?

Can any one please suggest me, thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you want. If you don't want the version that is currently in Developer Release to ever be seen by users, you should reject it. Then post a new binary and have it go through the review process.

If you want users to see the version that is currently in Developer Release then release it and then add a new version as usual and submit your newer update for that new version.